# Linux shared library version match

Tags: linux, linker, shared-libraries, glibc

I have 2 machines,  one is ubuntu 16.04, which has libc-2.23 installed.  another one is redhat 7, the libc version is 2.17

The following simple program is compiled on ubuntu and can run well on redhat 7.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  printf("hello world\n");
  double n = 4;
  printf("%e\n", sqrt(n));
  return 0;
}
```

but when I compile mongodb on ubuntu, and ship the binary to redhat 7, I get the following error.

```
[zhifan@rhel-2372970 ~]$ ldd mongod
./mongod: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.23' not found (required by ./mongod)
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd4313a000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007faaf5eb4000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007faaf5cac000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007faaf5aa7000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007faaf5891000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007faaf5675000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007faaf52b1000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000564cf2068000)
```

So my questions are:

1. When running a binary, how library loader decide the library (libc in this case) it found is ok to use?
2. I'm sure the exact same version of mongod (which is built by mongo inc) can run with libc-2.17, but why my build can't run with libc-2.17?

Comment: Simple : The `hello` program uses objects available in glibc-2.17 . I.e. no object **GLIBC_2.23** is used.  ...`mongodb` (compiled in Ubuntu) uses objects only available in glibc-2.23 .

Comment: Thanks @KnudLarsen:  see my question 2, the same code  with different building way can work well with libc-2.17.

Comment: When you make the mongodb build in Ubuntu with `-lm` you will need a libc that provides `libm` with the Ubuntu libc version = 2.23 . Rule "number 1" : Compile on older OS than the target.

Answer (score 1):

> When running a binary, how library loader decide the library (libc in this case) it found is ok to use?

It looks for symbol versions that are required by the application. IFF all required symbols are available, then the library is ok to use.

You can see what symbols are required by running `readelf -V a.out`.

> why my build can't run with libc-2.17

When you link your binary against `GLIBC-2.23`, you *may use* symbol definitions from that version. These symbols have a different ABI, compared to earlier version, and therefore can't use earlier version.

To avoid this, you mist *either* build on older system (the binary will run on newer system just fine -- it will use older symbol ABI), or you must build a Linux-to-older-Linux cross-compiler (which will make your binary use older ABI).